# Fancybox custom caption( paragraph) under image when it click

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I have a question about Fancybox 3, I tried to add a container with list items under the image when the lightbox is firing, it's not just a caption. I've been google around and check the sample code from the documentation.
The closest one I found is this:https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/EbyQzE
but the caption only show image hover, and it's always sticking the bottom of the browser, what I tried to work on is, stick after the image, and show all the time when lightbox trigger, and I also want to set image for center height.

**HTML**

```
<a href="assets/images/sample.jpg" class="img-container fancybox" data-caption="Sample 1" data-fancybox="sample">
  <img class="lazyload" data-src="/assets/images//sample.jpg" src="assets/images/sample.jpg" alt="sample 1">
</a>

<div class="content">
   <ul>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 2</li>
      <li>Test 3</li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('[data-fancybox="sample"]').fancybox({
    infobar: true,
    loop: true,
    arrows: true,
    caption: function (instance, item) {
        return $(this).next().html();
        },
    afterLoad : function(instance, current) {
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

    if ( pixelRatio > 1.5 ) {
    current.width  = current.width  / pixelRatio;
    current.height = current.height / pixelRatio;
    }
    }
});
```

I use CSS to center and style the caption, but I want it dynamically add it under the image no what size/height image is.

Sample code:
https://codepen.io/Madebymt/pen/rPRrNW

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can define html tags inside data-caption, so using that property you can add container with list items under the image. Though it will be treated as caption, you can always style the class 'content' to give it a look and feel of your choice.

Comment: Can you create a mockup of "under the image no what size/height image is" and how it would look for small/big images and long/short caption on various screen sizes?

Comment: Here's the sample I create and the issue I had:https://codepen.io/Madebymt/pen/rPRrNW Thank you